# community user not able to populate lookup field which has lookup filter

Tags: lookup-filter

I have a custom lookup field(contact lookup) in Lead object. Previously both internal & community user are able to populate value for this field. now we have enabled lookup filter condition, after this community users are not able to populate value for this field.

Even though they provided the correct value which satisfy the filter condition, the lookup didn't give any results. Kindly help me.

Comment: May be community user doesn't have view all permission for that object.

Comment: We shouldn't give view all permission to community user for that object (Lead & Contact). They were able to populate with out filter, after filter only problem

Answer (score 0):

We have to place the filter field into the page layout (only for lightning). I forgot to place it for community user page layout.